# Font size control in table

Tags: tables, fontsize

I have a table that is too wide to fit in a page. How to change the font size in a table?

[image]

This is the source code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table*}[ht]
    \caption{Dissemination Time and Success in ONE Simulation}
    %\vspace{-.25cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l ccc c ccc c ccc c ccc}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{7}{c}{1K/2K byte budget} && \multicolumn{7}{c}{5K byte budget}\\
    \cmidrule{2-8} \cmidrule{10-16}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{success (\%)} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{time (s)} &&\multicolumn{3}{c}{success (\%)} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{time (s)} \\
    \addlinespace
    & FBF & Labeled & JSON && FBF & Labeled & JSON && FBF & Labeled & JSON  && FBF & Labeled & JSON\\
    \midrule
    {\em Manhattan} & 100\% & 67\% & 67\% && 1248 & 1820 & 2446 && 100\% & 100\% & 100\% && 675 & 583 & 1485\\
    {\em mini-Manhattan} & 27\% & 11\% & 16\% && 329 & 315 & 208 && 78\% & 53\% & 33\% && 263 & 364 & 308\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:dissemination}
    \vspace{-.25cm}
    \end{table*}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: After `\centering`, you could revise as `\scriptsize\makebox[\textwidth]{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}` or even `\tiny` if needed.

Comment: What is `\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[c]{.1\linewidth}{\centering }}` supposed to do? Looks like it can just be omitted. Please state the dimensions of the text block -- especially its width.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- wouldn't `\scriptsize` be better placed just before `\begin{tabular}`, inside the box?

Comment: Please also tell us which document class you used for the two-column version of the document.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You are right in general, though in this particular instance, I do not think there is any difference

Comment: @Mico: Removed the line you pointed out. Well, for the two column, I used \documentclass[conference, 10pt]{IEEEtran} class.

Comment: @Mico: I got it, updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the table fit if you (a) set reasonably tight page margins (say, 1" wide); (b) set the relative font size to `\footnotesize` (a 20% linear reduction from `\normalsize`), (c) get rid of the three empty columns and (d) use a `tabular*` environment (with width set to `\textwidth`) and let LaTeX figure out the amount of whitespace that can be inserted between the columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,size=footnotesize}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\caption{Dissemination Time and Success in ONE Simulation}
\label{table:dissemination}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{c}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{1K/2K byte budget} 
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{5K byte budget}\\
\cmidrule{2-7} \cmidrule{8-13}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{success (\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{time (s)} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{success (\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{time (s)} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10} \cmidrule{11-13}
& FBF & Labeled & JSON & FBF & Labeled & JSON 
& FBF & Labeled & JSON & FBF & Labeled & JSON\\
\midrule
\em Manhattan & 100\% & 67\% & 67\% & 1248 & 1820 & 2446 & 100\% & 100\% & 100\% & 675 & 583 & 1485\\
\em mini-Manhattan & 27\% & 11\% & 16\% & 329 & 315 & 208 & 78\% & 53\% & 33\% & 263 & 364 & 308\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, if there's a way to use a narrower header label than "Labeled", a lot of space could be freed up. This could be put to use to use a larger font size and/or create more (and more evenly distributed) intercolumn whitespace.